# Farseer Physics 3.5 Bayazit Algorithm/Decomposer

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

How do I get to the `BayazitDecomposer` in XNA with Farseer Physics? I am trying to convert my texture to a body. It should be

```
BayazitDecomposer.ConvexPartion(verticies);
```

But that doesn't exist in Farseer Physics 3.5 I was wondering if anybody knew where it could be found?

Also, does Farseer Physics have an active forum or an updated documentation for this? I can't seem to find one and it would really help if I could post there instead of here as it's probably annoying you all.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my first question, to use the algorithms and stuff, you need to do this:

```
FarseerPhysics.Common.Decomposition.Triangulate.ConvexPartition(verticies, FarseerPhysics.Common.Decomposition.TriangulationAlgorithm.Bayazit);
```

You can also swap Bayazit with whatever other one you want to use.